# How to set href to different values?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I set the value of the href based on a variable value.
    As of now, I have the follwing code:

`<a href="javascript:clearDate('txtDueDate');"`

Waht I need is shown below. I want the href value to be disabled if `udisable` is true.

```
var udisable = '<%=dueDateDisabled %>';
if (udisable == "false")
         <a href="javascript:clearDate('txtDueDate');"
      else
          <a href="javascript:void(0);"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<a href="javascript:if (udisable == "false) {clearDate('txtDueDate');}"/>
```

or even better: Create your own function encapsulating this:

```
// In some JavaScript file:
function clearDate2(dateString) {
    if (udisable == "false") {
        clearDate(datestring);
    }   
}

-----

<a href="javascript:clearDate2('txtDueDate');"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is ASP.Net?

If so you need to ask - where am I making this decision? On the client or on the server? In this case you really *need* to do it on the server, and indeed it looks like you intended to, but then got mixed up with client-side javascript as well.  The following block will output one or other anchor tag:

```
<% if(dueDateDisabled) { %>
  <a href="javascript:clearDate('txtDueDate');" <% }
   else { %>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" <% } %>
```

*Note I've left off the rest of the anchor tag because you do in your question*

Now when the server renders the page, you will only see one or the other anchor in the page output.

Your original code won't work because you can't mix javascript and html like that - you need to do this on the server; unless you want to do `document.write` on the client (which I don't recommend in this scenario), or manipulating the DOM in javascript either directly or through something like jQuery.  Which really, as I say, you don't want to do.

Comment: Server side is definitely the way to go if possible (rather than using the server side to feed the client side to modify the DOM...)

Comment: Absolutely - I've come across one or two rare scenarios where outputting server side data into on-page javascript has been useful; but especially in this scenario it actually doesn't make sense!